# TCP-IP Join in Hazelcast not working in servicemix

Tags: hazelcast, apache-karaf, apache-servicemix

According hazelcast article http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/2.4/manual/html/ch12s02.html      added hostname of another PC in hazelcast.xml which is generated in SERVICEMIX_HOME/etc like below.

```
<tcp-ip enabled="true">
    <hostname>FABLRDT061:5702</hostname>
    <interface>127.0.0.1</interface>
</tcp-ip>
```

If i start the servicemix, its not able to connect to the hostname i specified because of the following connection refusal. The log message in the other pc is as below

```
[172.16.25.64]:5702 [cellar] 5702 is accepting socket connection from /172.16.25.71:60770
[172.16.25.64]:5702 [cellar] 5702 accepted socket connection from /172.16.25.71:60770
[172.16.25.64]:5702 [cellar] Wrong bind request from Address[127.0.0.1]:5701! This node is not requested endpoint: Address[FABLRDT061]:5702
[172.16.25.64]:5702 [cellar] Connection [/172.16.25.71:60770] lost. Reason: Explicit close
```

what could be the reason?? Can someone help me out??

Comment: And if you skip the `interface` config bit would it work? Just asking ...

Comment: The current system will not be discovered if interface is removed.

Answer (score 1):

Hazelcast is configuration file using which discovery of nodes can be configured.

Eventhough the tutorials explain the following points,
According to the hands on i did, i understand that

1. Multicast is for auto discovery of cellar nodes in same sytem.
2. If cellar nodes are present in different systems over network, we use tcp-ip configuration.
3. For multicasting we dont need to change anything until we writing different multicast groups.
4. For discovering nodes using tcp-ip we need to specify ipaddresses (as explained by many tutorials but not exactly how.
5. under `tcp-ip` tag create a tag called `hostname` in which the hostname of the other system or ipaddress should be mentioned. In the `interface` tag, specify the current system's ipaddress.
6. Similarly in other nodes same should be done.

Answer (score 1):

I would stay away from using hostnames, but replace it by ip addresses.